# How to seed with model that has relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have `User` and `Activity` models. `User` **hasMany** relationship to `Activity` (and an `Activity` **belongsTo** only one `User`):

In User model:

```
public function activities() {
    return $this->hasMany(Activity::class);
}
```

I want to seed the users with their corresponding activities. I tried this but did not work:

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
        $user->activities()->saveMany(factory(App\Activity::class, 2)->make());
    });
}
```

ActivityFactory:

```
$factory->define(App\Activity::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'        => $faker->text(50),
        'description'  => $faker->text(200)
    ];
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please can you show the factory for the `Activity` model.

Comment: @RossWilson i added it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

**database/factories/ActivityFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\Activity::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory('App\User')->create()->id,
        'title'        => $faker->text(50),
        'description'  => $faker->text(200),
    ];
});
```

**database/seeds/ActivitySeeder.php**

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Activity::class, 10)->create();
}
```

And then run for the activity seed.

```
php artisan make:seeder ActivitySeeder
```